# Removing last consecutive digits

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a column of alphanumeric data and i have to remove the last consecutive digits. It could be of any length.

**Input:**

```
dlxcp01 
dlcs8012
fg2fdes1
```

**Desired Output:**

```
dlxcp
dlcs
fg2fdes
```

As i have large dataset, a right code would do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sub function.

```
sub("[0-9]+$", "", x)
```

or

```
sub("[[:digit:]]+$", "", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `gsub()` function:

```
text <- c('dlxcp01', 'dlcs8012', 'fg2fdes1')
gsub('[0-9]*$', "", text)
[1] "dlxcp"   "dlcs"    "fg2fdes"
```

Comment: what's the need for `*` and `gsub` function?

Comment: The `*` expands the selection as far as the pattern will allow, otherwise it would only substitute the very last character that matches `"[0-9]"`

Comment: I don't think it matters whether one uses `*` or `+` in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it matters performance wise.. `[0-9]*$` matches all the line end if there is no digits exists at the last if there is any digits at the last then it matches those. Where `[0-9]+` matches all the digits exists only at the line end.

Comment: And also, in this case, replacement should occur for only one time. So no need for gsub..

Comment: Your language is hard to decipher, but it appears that your answer has better performance.